# Adding an argument when calling main from another program or the command line

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

Sorry if this has been asked before.

Essentially I have a program that essentially runs like this:

```
    def __init__(self, config, system='Mandarin'):
        self.surf_conc_mode = 'uniform'
        self.flow_transitions = self.gen_flow_transitions()
        self.concs = self.get_concs(system)

    def get_concs(self, system):
        if system == 'Mandarin': 
            concs[0,0] = config['M_internal_Cl_conc']
            concs[1,0] = config['M_external_Cl_conc']
            concs[0,1] = 10**(-1*config['M_internal_pH']) * 1E3
            concs[1,1] = 10**(-1*config['M_external_pH']) * 1E3
       else: 
         (concs is defined differently here)
```

The config program is reading in stuff from the config input file:

```
 def gen_config_args_MKM():
    config_args = dict()
    config_args['input_rate_file'] = (True, str)
    config_args['rate_map_file'] = (True, str)
    config_args['M_internal_pH'] = (True, float)
    config_args['M_external_pH'] = (True, float)
    config_args['M_internal_Cl_conc'] = (True, float)
    config_args['M_external_Cl_conc'] = (True, float)
```

And all of this is called in the executable script right here (lets say its run_fruit.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import numpy as np
import math
import copy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from ClC_MKM.src.Fruit_sys import Fruit_sys
import ClC_MKM.src.Config as conf

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('config',
        help='Configuration file (.txt)',
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    configs = conf.read_config_MKM(args.config)
    N = len(configs)

main()
```

I have tried to add in the 'system' to the argparse so I can call for it by saying:

```
parser.add_argument('system', help='Mandarin or Apple system')
```

But when I try to run:

```
 run_fruit config.txt Apple
```

It says it cannot recognize the input 'Apple' into the script. How could I add this to be callable from the command line?

Right now the default value in Fruit_sys def makes it not super important but I have an optimizer script that is literally pulling all of the aspects from this system to run in the optimization scheme and I am hoping to optimize against both scenarios rather than just Mandarin:

```
   self.fruit_systems.append(Fruit_sys(fruit_configs[0]))
```

Which runs Fruit_sys as only the default scenario and does not let me specify any additional fruit type since it is calling it like it would in the command line.

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly where is the new `add_argument` added?  And what is the full error message?

Comment: So I added it right before args = parser.parse_args() The exact error is run_fruit.py: error: unrecognized arguments: Mandarin

Comment: Did the error include a usage line?

Comment: It did not, it's just the single line that I have here. I wish it showed some tracing.

Comment: What does `run_fruit -h` (or `--help`) do?

Comment: It just says ' configuration file (.txt)'. So it is completely ignoring my additional add argument line.

Comment: There's another parser that's running before yours.  If it has any problems, or sees the '-h', it acts and exits.  Your parser is not being run at all.

Comment: So how would I fix this? I have this single argparse example above and just want to add one additional component. Would I be able to do it in 1 line like: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('config', 'system'
        help='Configuration file (.txt)',
    )